# JQuery function is not called in PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam new in php. I am trying to popup login window on click.but it is not working
This  is my header_view

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>Assets/js/popuplogin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>Assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div  id="rightcorner">
        <a href="#"  id="loginlink" >Log In</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

I included the below code in home.php(controller)

```
$this->load->library('javascript');
$this->load->library('javascript/jquery');
$this->load->helper(array('form'));
$data['library_src'] = $this->jquery->script();
$data['script_head'] = $this->jquery->_compile();
```

below is my popuplogin.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $("#loginlink").click(function(){   
        $("#logindiv").css("display","block");
    });
```

When I click on loginlink nothing happened.
Pls help me.

Comment: I strongly suspect you're getting at least one error in the browser's JavaScript console.  What is that error?

Comment: Hi david  Yes I got an error that is " Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined  Assets/js/popuplogin.js:1"

Comment: Yes it is working .The problem was load first jquery library first. thank u thank u so much